# SnowSQL CLI Error while loading csv file into user stage using PUT command

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[Please click here for the error screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlotA.jpg)

I m trying to load files in my user stage using SnowSQL CLI. I m unable to load the file neither in internal stage nor in my user stage. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is space in the folder name at 'Amarnath Eklare'.

You can either put the file in the folder where there is no space in any folder name or enclose the path in the PUT command in a single quote.
Something like the below should work:

put 'file://C:/snowflake stuff/gs_fk.csv' @~;

Screenshot below:-
[enter image description here][1]

~Mohit
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1da7.png